# mysql container won't start - Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine

Tags: mysql, docker, innodb

My container suddenly crashed and now it won't start:

This is the log of the start and error/shutdown:

```
Starting dev-laradock_mysql_1 ... done
                                                                                Attaching to dev-laradock_mysql_1
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:37.622458Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:37.622522Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:37.624025Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405115Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 12 for {space: 14398, page_no:37} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405123Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 13 for {space: 14398, page_no:1} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405129Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 21 for {space: 14398, page_no:31} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405139Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 23 for {space: 14398, page_no:36} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405144Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 53 for {space: 14398, page_no:26} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405151Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 54 for {space: 14398, page_no:25} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405157Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 55 for {space: 14398, page_no:23} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405168Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 57 for {space: 14398, page_no:1} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405173Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 58 for {space: 14398, page_no:4} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405179Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 59 for {space: 14398, page_no:27} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405185Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 60 for {space: 14398, page_no:0} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405195Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 61 for {space: 14398, page_no:2} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405201Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 62 for {space: 14398, page_no:24} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405206Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 63 for {space: 14398, page_no:5} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405212Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 64 for {space: 14398, page_no:28} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405232Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 65 for {space: 14398, page_no:22} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405237Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 66 for {space: 14398, page_no:29} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405242Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 67 for {space: 14398, page_no:30} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405248Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 68 for {space: 14398, page_no:6} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405260Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 69 for {space: 14398, page_no:21} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405265Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 70 for {space: 14398, page_no:31} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405271Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 71 for {space: 14398, page_no:17} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405277Z 1 [Warning] [MY-013088] [InnoDB] Doublewrite page 72 for {space: 14398, page_no:32} could not be restored. File name unknown for tablespace ID 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405291Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012179] [InnoDB] Could not find any file associated with the tablespace ID: 14398
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.405301Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012964] [InnoDB] Use --innodb-directories to find the tablespace files. If that fails then use --innodb-force-recovery=1 to ignore this and to permanently lose all changes to the missing tablespace(s)
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:41.505537Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:42.006337Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:42.006486Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:42.006905Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
mysql_1                | 2021-04-19T14:40:42.009937Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

The only thing I did recently was create a new docker container / project which had mysql involved, but I don't know how that would corrupt this one. Initially when I started up, everything worked fine. I was in my app which interacts with the database, but then it crashed

Comment: I hope you are not sharing the disk files between instances of MySQL?

Comment: @RickJames I have no idea. My "fix" was to delete some of the temp files that get stored by mysql. and a laravel package kept crashing mysql, so I did a database reset. but it could happen again and I don't know the cause. can only assume it was because I had a new docker project that used mysql? by sharing disk files you mean the two containers are writing to the same area on the host machine?

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me, was giving me this error after the mysql version of the docker service has been upgraded;

- `docker-compose down -v` - Which stops and removes all the running services and volumes.
- `docker system prune --volumes` - Which completely removes volumes and cache.
- `docker-compose up -d` - Which pulls and creates the services again.

Answer (score 1):

1. deleet the old mysql files
2. delete the old mysql container/pod
3. deploy the new mysql v 8
4. solved the issue for me